# jquery input.focus + wrap can't type in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
      $(this).next("div.description").slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).wrap(' <
          div > < /div>').select('input'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blink>
  <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="35" id="editfiled" name="somename" maxlength="128">
  <div class="description">
    <p>some text</p>
</blink>
```

and after that I can't type in this input.

I need that if input gets focus it must be highlighted inside div.

Comment: Why do you need that `blink` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run into a circle.

If the input gets the focus, you wrap it into the div.
As this is a rebuilding of the markup, the input will lose the focus. If you click on it again, focus will be triggered again, another div will be wrapped around the input and so on.

You could try it like that:

```
$('input').focus(function () {      
  if(!$(this).data('wrapper'))
  {
      $(this).next("div.description").slideToggle("slow");

      $(this).data('wrapper',$(this).wrap('<div/>').parent());
      var _this=this;
      setTimeout(function(){_this.focus();},10);
  }
  else
  {
    this.select();
  }
});
```

It stores the wrapper-div as data() of the input, so if the input is already wrapped, the function would'nt do anything.

Don't forget to remove the wrapper from data() too if you somewhere remove the div wrapped around the input.

(In Firefox the selection is lost when slideToggle is finished, maybe you need another solution to show/hide the description)

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this (no parameters to the [`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) call):

```
$('input').focus(function () {  
   $(this).next("div.description").slideToggle("slow");
   $(this).wrap('<div></div>').select();
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/m2JcL/).

Comment: still problem is there. input sill blocked

Comment: @sjcris - in which browser? I'm not have any issues with the demo here.